# Can someone explain partitions to me?

Tags: partitioning, disk

I'm installing Lubuntu and I and dual-booting it with Windows 7. I want to be able to access all files while using either OS. My Hard drive has 4 partitions,

1. sda1 200mb 'Windows 7 (Loader)',
2. sda2 480gb 'Window 7 (Loader)',
3. sda3 18gb 'Windows recovery' (or something close to that),
4. sda4 100mb and no 'System' on it.

1,2 and 3 are all 'NTFS' (I think it was) and sda4 is FAT32. I don't know what FAT32 or NTFS mean, so can

1) Someone explain what FAT32/NTFS mean and do.

2) How I can make files on the biggest partition (sda2 480 GB 'Windows 7(Loader)'), available to both operating systems.

Bare in mind I am completely new to this area of computing and have next to no idea what I'm doing. Thank you :D

Comment: Have you either googled or looked at wikipedia to answer 1?  I believe you will also find a lot of references to 2 on google as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FAT32`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32#FAT32) and [`NTFS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) are both [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). Each file system has its own way for storing and retrieving data.

Windows can use `FAT` (`FAT*`), `exFAT` and `NTFS`, where `NTFS` is the default.

Linux can use `ext` (`ext*`), `ZFS`, `ReiserFS`, `btrfs` and a lot more, including every file system Windows can use, where `ext*` is the default (usually `ext3` or `ext4`).

So, if you want to be able to share data between Windows and Linux, you should choose a file system both operating systems can use. I suggest `NTFS`, as `FAT` and `exFAT` have their limits.

However, you **cannot** install Linux on a `NTFS` partition, so you should create a seperate system partition (`ext*`) to install Linux on.

---

You'll have to [resize](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) partitions in order to create a new partition (for Linux), because you're already using your whole disk for Windows (`NTFS`).

This **may** cause data corruption, so please make a backup of your important files before you do this, or make an [image](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2029832/backing-up-your-entire-drive-cloning-vs-imaging.html) of your whole hard drive.

Comment: So I should make sda2 smaller and create a partition in ext4 to install Lubuntu on? (How big should this partition be?)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You can make the partition as big as you want. The minimal size is 5 GB (according to Ubuntu's [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)), but I would make it at least 20 GB to preserve some space for updates, programs you want to install, temp files and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) - In computing, a file system (or filesystem) is used to control how data is stored and retrieved. Without a file system, information placed in a storage area would be one large body of data with no way to tell where one piece of information stops and the next begins.

- **NTFS** -> New Technology File System
- **FAT32** -> File Allocation Table

NTFS is newer File System by Microsoft and replacement to FAT32. One of the major drawback of FAT32 is that you cannot have a file of size greater than 4 GB.

Linux uses **ext4** file system. Linux can only be installed on ext4 and Newer windows like 7,8 & Vista can be installed only on NTFS (maybe also on FAT32). You can access Windows NTFS & FAT32 partition from ubuntu but you cannot access ext4 from windows (Microsoft does not support ext4)

To access **sda2** in Ubuntu open a terminal and enter following commands

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda2
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
```

then you can access+modify sda2 from `/mnt/sda2`

Comment: So I should make sda2 smaller and create a partition in ext4 to install Lubuntu on? (How big should this partition be?)

Comment: You need to make some partition smaller and my suggestion is that you make sda2 smaller and create a new partition of around 30-50 GB for Lubuntu from it

Comment: I made sda2 smaller but now it says that the 10 gigabytes that it left unused are unusable?

Comment: you can create a partition from unused space. Dont worry about file-system of partition you can always change file-system by formatting the new partition

Comment: It doesn't give me an option to do that though

Comment: I am stuck with 'unusuable' at 9999mb

Comment: how did you resized you partition??

Comment: using the 'change' tool in the Lubuntu installer

Comment: I reduced it by 10 gb

Comment: The better way to resize that partition is making that from windows. You risk an unbootable windows otherwise. Ever use the tools of the OS that created the partition... And the other problem is that if the partition table is the classic one, you have to transform one of the partition to an extended one (otherwise the total number of partition can't be higher than 4)

Comment: If sda4 is not used, delete it, merge the space, and create an extended partition from it. BACKUP FIRST (although changing an NTFS filesystem from gparted could have well killed it already).